# How to get value for checkbox in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm using JQuery to POST a form.  I'm having trouble getting the proper value from this field:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="facebook" value="true" checked="checked" id="facebook"/>
```

My JQuery:

```
var facebook = $("input#facebook").val();
```

I realize now that I'm getting the value with is always "true" regardless of being checked or not.  So how do I get whether it's checked or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var facebook = $('input#facebook').is(':checked');
```