# How to get value of Rad Button which is used like checkbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I want to get the value of RadButton which is used like checkbox.

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButtonCheck" runat="server" ButtonType="ToggleButton" 
Checked="false" Text="StackOverflow" ToggleType="CheckBox" Enabled="true" AutoPostBack="false">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

I have read this question and answer and more..
[How to get value for checkbox in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743387/how-to-get-value-for-checkbox-in-jquery)
But

```
$('#<%=RadButtonCheck.ClientID%>').is(':checked') //always returns false.
```

How can I get the correct value?

Edited:

Also .attr('checked') attribute returns nothing and it gives error..

Comment: Usually this kind of buttons are warped with some span, or other elements that makes them fancy, and the 'RadButtonCheck.ClientID' is not actually the check control. Check what is rendered, then read how to get the check control. Also they may look like checkbox, but its may be something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most suitable answer for my question is:

```
var button = $find("<%= stackoverflow.ClientID%>");
if(button.get_checked())
{
     alert("is checked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look on this page http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/radiosandcheckboxes/defaultcs.aspx  and looking at the rendered html it looks like you can call

```
$('#<%=RadButtonCheck.ClientID%>').val();
```

Which should return "Checked" or "Unchecked". It might differ slightly depending on the exact control but as Aristos suggests you need to look at the rendered HTML.

Alternatively use the RAD Controls Client API found here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/clientsideapi/defaultcs.aspx and here http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-client-side-basics.html in order to access the checked value. I think you need to call .get_checked() method.

Comment: .val() returns empty string like "".

Comment: can you post the rendered output?

Comment: I meant the rendered output of the page - the generated html.

Answer (score 1):

All Telerik RadControls have a rich client side API - which includes properties and methods. In your case i assume you want to know on the client side whether the user has checked the RadButton whose toggle type is CheckBox type.

You can listen for the client side OnClientCheckedChanged event. This event will get you the sender i.e. RadButton which was clicked and event args which is of Type radButtonCheckedEventArgs. This contains get_checked() method which will let you know if the checked state is true (meaning checked) or false (meaning not checked). Here is the code snippet to achieve this:

```
<div>
        <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButtonCheck" runat="server" 
         ButtonType="ToggleButton" Checked="false" 
         Text="StackOverflow" ToggleType="CheckBox" Enabled="true" 
         AutoPostBack="false" OnClientCheckedChanged="onClientCheckedChanged">
        </telerik:RadButton>
    </div>
        <script>
            function onClientCheckedChanged(sender, args) {
                alert(args.get_checked());
            }
        </script>
```

Here is the documentation link for the client side event:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-onclientcheckedchanged.html

Hope this answers your question.

Lohith (Tech Evangelist, Telerik India)

Answer (score 0):

Can you set a name for the radio button and then try to get the checked value by the name? Something like this:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButtonCheck" runat="server" ButtonType="ToggleButton"  Checked="false" Text="StackOverflow" ToggleType="CheckBox" Enabled="true" AutoPostBack="false" name="myRadio"> </telerik:RadButton> 

$('input:radio[name=myRadio]:checked').val();
```

Comment: Sorry, it should be the name and not the class in the html set to 'myRadio'. Can you please try again?